# How to return summed array from computed using reduce function. Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to js, sorry if I describe it not well enough to understand where I struggle, it's really not easy to explain what I need.

I have computed function where use reduce method to loop my objects, make some calculations inside of loop to find new variables and return array with summed values.

I know how to return sum of value inside of the loop but for only one variable, I don't know how to return 2 variables from computed, that's why I think to turn this 2 values into array and return sum somehow, to use this 2 values in future calculations. Please tip me, where to dig.
My code explain the issue better:

```js
 new Vue({
        el: "#demo",
        data() {
            return {
            objects: {
                price: 0,
                amount: 0,
                percent: 0,
                fee: 0,
                solution_cost: {dry:0, wet: 0}
            },
        },
        computed: {
            solutionCost() {
                //Looping thru my objects
                const total = this.objects.reduce((sum, object) => {

                    solution_cost_dry = object.amount / object.price;
                    solution_cost_wet = object.solution_cost[dry] * object.percent;

                    // Don't undestand how to get sum vor "dry" and "wet" and put it summed into array
                    return object.solution_cost: sum + {dry:solution_cost_dry, wet:solution_cost_wet  }

                }, 0)

                //return array with summed values {dry:solution_cost_dry, wet:solution_cost_wet  }
                return total[];
            },
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're not trying to return an array, you're trying to return an object with two keys

Comment: try `return sum + solution_cost_dry + solution_cost_wet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added **//CHANGE** comments to the code where I changed logic.  You need to pass in an initial object of what you want to return, and update the nested keys for the totals.

```js
computed: {
    solutionCost() {
        //Looping thru my objects
        const total = this.objects.reduce((sum, object) => {
            solution_cost_dry = object.amount / object.price;
            solution_cost_wet = object.solution_cost[dry] * object.percent;

            //CHANGE: add the values to the totals
            sum.dry += solution_cost_dry;
            sum.wet += solution_cost_wet;
            
            return sum;
        }, {dry:0, wet:0}) //CHANGE: Make the initial "sum" be the object with each key with a zero value

        //return array with summed values {dry:solution_cost_dry, wet:solution_cost_wet  }
        return total;
    },
}
```

Comment: `return total[];` should be `return total;`